# Split brain on DRBD and Pacemaker cluster

Tags: cluster, drbd, pacemaker

I want to put into your consideration the following situation that is currently happening on our active-passive cluster (DRBD, Pacemaker, Corosync, PostgreSQL)

OS: Ubuntu server 14.04 x64
DRBD: 8.4
Pacemaker: 1.1.10
Corosync: 2.3.3
PostgreSQL: 9.3

Here is the problem:
When primary goes down, the secondary is elected as primary. The problem comes in at the time of re-introducing the previous primary, it goes directly to a split-brain situation when it should become a secondary instead. Here is the detailed sequence of events and respective logs:

### A: Primary, B: Secondary

**1-** A goes DOWN

**2-** B becomes PRIMARY

**3-** A starts again --> SPLIT BRAIN (We presumed that on this case the failover could be done automatically)

LOGS from A:

```
Jan 28 16:15:11 node1 kernel: [  538.025422] block drbd0: helper command: /sbin/drbdadm initial-split-brain minor-0
Jan 28 16:15:11 node1 kernel: [  538.026185] block drbd0: helper command: /sbin/drbdadm initial-split-brain minor-0 exit code 0 (0x0)
Jan 28 16:15:11 node1 kernel: [  538.026194] block drbd0: Split-Brain detected but unresolved, dropping connection!
```

DRBD status:

```
service drbd status
drbd driver loaded OK; device status:
version: 8.4.3 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: F97798065516C94BE0F27DC 
m:res  cs          ro                 ds                   p       mounted  fstype
0:pg   StandAlone  Secondary/Unknown  Consistent/DUnknown  r-----
```

AFAIS it seems that DRBD broke the state of this node.

My questions are:

1- Is my assumption correct that on event 3, the returning node can be automatically joint to the cluster?

2- If it can be done, please tell how.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Is my assumption correct that on event 3, the returning node can be
>   automatically joint to the cluster?

Yes, this can be done. DRBD should not go Primary on it's own unless told to in the resource configuration; check that the 'startup { become-primary-on  }' definition is not set in the resource configs.

> 2- If it can be done, please tell how.

Check that the following are true:

a. 'drbd' is not set to start at boot ('chkconfig drbd off' in RHEL, 'update-rc.d drbd disable' in Debian).

b. DRBD should not be configured to become primary on it's own (as mentioned above).

The DRBD user's guide has a section on configuring DRBD for use with Pacemaker that might help if my answer above doesn't do the trick: https://drbd.linbit.com/users-guide/ch-pacemaker.html